# Overflow Indicator Solution alongside FlexBox Column Layout?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular, user-interface

**I wanted to add some clarity to this question in case it is not immediately clear - but we are *not* required to provide a CSS only solution.  This project will be data driven and we are perfectly fine with bringing in JS to help assist with this solution.**

---

**Hello!**  Thanks so much for taking the time to stop by.

*In a nutshell*, we have an interesting problem where we would like to supplement FlexBox column layout with the ability to break the content at certain points using what we have dubbed, "Overflow Indicators".

***Take a look at this:***

[image]

I've also attempted doing some examples around this, but admittedly I am more of a UX Designer than I am developer, see here: (*am I close?*)

https://codepen.io/cclark413/pen/XvxbqV

```js
var detectWrap = function(className) {
  
  var wrappedItems = [];
  var prevItem = {};
  var currItem = {};
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    currItem = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (prevItem && prevItem.top > currItem.top) {
      wrappedItems.push(items[i]);
    }
    prevItem = currItem;
  };
  
  return wrappedItems;

}

window.onload = function(event){
  var wrappedItems = detectWrap('block');
  for (var k = 0; k < wrappedItems.length; k++) {
    wrappedItems[k].classList.add("wrapped")
    wrappedItems[k].innerText= "I wrapped!"
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
div.container {
  padding:15px 0;
  background-color:black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:1024px;
  height:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}  
div.container > div {
  margin:0 15px;
  width:33.3%;
}
.header, .footer {
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#333;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:10px;
}
.item {
  background-color:#e1e1e1;
  padding:15px;
}
div.spacer {
  background-color:transparent !important;
  height:15px;
}
div.wrapped {
  color:white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header block">
    <div class="row">
      Row 1 Header
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      Row 2 Header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item block">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 3</div>
  <div class="footer block">Test</div>
  <div class="spacer block"></div>
  <div class="header block">Header 2</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item block">Item 5</div>
  <div class="footer block">Test</div>
</div>
```

I have a small problem with the solution above, however:
- The content is treated individual under the container as opposed to "Coagulated Panels" this limits us from doing things to the panel itself it would appear, and we need to find a good way to provide containers around the individual panel content after they have been broken for overflow.  I just broke everything out to use native flex capabilities for now.

Flexbox is excellent for getting us part way there, but it is not *smart* enough to take flex content and utilize space completely.  We want to add to that complicated request by imposing ***Overflow Indicators*** (Basically a jagged edge in the UI which looks as though the panel has been torn and started in a new column)

Some rules:

- This is a web interface, currently using Angular, HTML, CSS.
- The header/footer should never be standalone. Header should always be with item one, and the footer should always be with the last item. Breaking a panel up any other way is acceptable.
- We want an elegant solution for the jagged edge so that it can be configured with certain background colors to match the rest of the panel in certain states (i.e. Disabled, Active, Cancelled, etc) - so we would prefer not to have a image based solution other than perhaps a versatile SVG.
- While we would like this content to overflow the page with a pagination solution, we would still want the ability to bring in a horizontal scrolling to view panels in the future.

It may even be an *assumption* that FlexBox is the right answer here and not some other solution.  Looking forward to seeing the creativity for a solution!

Comment: Why don't you give us some html and css with what you have first so there is a reference point

Comment: @Keith Added some code I have been messing with.

Comment: great thanks, will see what we can do

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [CSS Multi-Column Layout Module](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/) (not the same as `flex-box`) is designed to do pretty much what you're asking for and its [reasonably well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%20Multiple%20column%20layout).

There are a few caveats though:

1. The CSS does the column flow for you so I'm not sure if you'll get the indicators when crossing columns. I'm still looking into that.
2. The web really isn't created with "pagination" in mind so splitting content into multiple columned containers may not work. You could very easily add more columns and scroll the container though.

### Columns Example

```css
.columns {
 margin: 30px;
 columns: 3;
}

.item {
    padding: 4px;
    background: #ddd;
}

header, 
footer, 
li {
 display:block;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 background: #333;
 color: #eee;
}
footer {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 background: #eee;
 color: #333;
}

header, 
footer, 
ul>li:first-child, 
ul>li:last-child {
 -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
 
 <div class="items">
 <!-- using a list to so :first/:last child work -->
        <!-- probably don't even need the "items" wrapper but it makes everthing a bit cleaner -->
  <header>Header</header>
  <ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="items">
  <header>Header</header>
  <ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
 </div>
 
 <div class="items">
  <header>Header</header>
  <ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
 </div>
 
 <div class="items">
  <header>Header</header>
  <ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Edit:

### Adding "rag edge to first/last in column"

I've been trying to solve the column split indicators using `pseudo-elements` that sit behind the next/previous but there are some odd issues. Namely, the Column container acts as if it has `overflow: hidden` but there's no way to override it (known bug). The option is to create a local `stacking context` with something like `will-change` but that poses it's own issues.

You can follow my progress in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/zYOrPMZ).

Comment: Thanks Bryce!  Rockstar.  This is looking pretty good so far.  A lot of these principles I was not aware of.  A few questions:
* It looks like this requires the columns to be filled first?  Any thoughts on how this would fill the available vertical real estate of one column before jumping to the next?
* Indicators stored as pseudo elements is creative.  I do wonder if injecting these via some JS might work better as they would allow some logic in addition to be applied according to the rules outlined.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @cclark413 You could specify a height, but the default is to flow the content across all columns. There's a setting to equalize col heights or just fill from the top/left. I think the JS route might be required BUT it has drawbacks like requiring recalculation when the window size changes, etc. So I'd prefer a solution that's all CSS if possible since it's responsive from the start.

Answer (score 0):

To implement that design in flexbox, you need to use a trick. Make sure you add pseudo element with lower z-index and have that element with ornament background. In this case all items will land like tiles on your house roof. I made example with lower triangles but the same approach could be used for upper ornament. Note: for top ornament the question is still opened (I tried ::before pseudo class and z-index is not working for that).
Here is the working example for lower ornament: https://codepen.io/emankovski/pen/jONWgpy

[image]

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.flex-item {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.header {
  margin-top:-5px;
}
.footer {
  z-index: 5;

  transform: translate(0px, -5px);
}

.item {
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  z-index: 5;
}

.item:after {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  transform: translate(0px, 8px);
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAICAYAAADA+m62AAAAQElEQVQoU2N8+PDhfwYiACO6Qnl5eQwxkDkogiBFMMPRDYArRFaETTFYITZF6IrhVuHzD8gwohSCPUNEyICVAADpLCXVkRgaFQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
    repeat;
}

.spacer {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">
    <div class="header">Header 1
    </div>Item 1</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item ">
    <div class="item panel-1">Item 4</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">
    <div class="header">Header 1
    </div>Item 1</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item flex-item panel-1">Item 7</div>
  <div class="flex-item ">
    <div class="item panel-1">Item 8</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used pattern generator from here:
http://www.patternify.com/

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eugene - I really appreciate you taking time to help us out.  My concern with flex is that it forces us to keep things separated as flex items, so when we want to do something collectively to order panels as far as structure we have to get even more creative.  It also seems somewhat hard to enforce the rules we have around breaking items at logical points and preventing things like a standalone header/footer.  Thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: Preventing standalone header and footer is easy. Header is rendered as a part of first item and footer gets enclosed in the last item. This way flexbox will keep them together, on the same column. I will update my example later. Collectively ordering panels is just a matter of ordering groups of items marked with for example the same class (like panel-1, panel-2 etc) or data- attribute.

Comment: @cclark413 See I updated example and code to prevent standalone header and footer.